# Cordova error could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Tags: cordova, gradle, cmd, environment-variables

I know this error is already everywhere on the internet, but all the fixes I tried didn't work.
I tried to change the value in gradle.properties from -Xmx2048m to -Xmx512m, -Xmx1024m but they both didn't work.
When i enter "cordova run android" it just changes back to -Xmx2048m.
Here is the error message I'm getting:
[image]
The java version I am running: "1.8.0_291"
Gradle version: "7.1.1"

Can someone please help me fix this, because I'm really lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. I was changing the RAM values in gradles.properties, but when I changed it from -Xmx2048m to -Xmx1024m in C:\Users\mauro\Projects\App\platforms\android\cordova\lib\config\GradlePropertiesParser, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue a while ago. Annother possibility is to provide the RAM values within the run command like:

```
cordova run android -- --jvmargs='-Xmx1024m'
```